# Eclipselink audit

Tags: persistence, eclipselink, audit

I have a problem with the creation of an audit using JPA / EclipseLink
I have found a lot of tutorials for Hibernate, but very little useful tuts about achieving this with EclipseLink.

Could you give me the pattern / idea how to achieve audit using JPA / EclipseLink or
helpful links to connect EclipseLink and Hibernate (@ Audit, Revisionlistener and others)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type of auditing do you require?

See,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Auditing

Comment: That message was written in behalf of my friend. He was struggling for couple of days with that problem and he eventually abandoned. Anyway - thanks for help :)